# How can i get the first entity from Object class

Tags: java

Updating the question,
How can i get the first object(TaskInstance) from Object, attached image below(obj)

[obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fFiZ.jpg)

though TaskInstance is present in obj Control is not going inside of if check

```
for(Object obj : taskInstanceEntities) {
  if(obj instanceof TaskInstance ){
    procurementDTOs.add(bidPreviewMapper.map((TaskInstance)obj));
  }
        }
```

---

I am getting a class cast exception for the below code, I have two Objects in taskList, say FirstTask and SecondTask.

How can I get the FirstTask object from obj. When i try to cast the taskList to FirstTask getting a class cast exception, because obj contains two objects(FirstTask and SecondTask), requesting the help to resolve my challenge.

```
List<Object> taskList = findByNamedQuery("<select query with multiple table join>");
List<FirstTask> firstTaskList = new ArrayList<FirstTask>();
for(Object obj : taskList){
    firstTaskList.add((FirstTask)obj);
}
```

Comment: That is really strange. I guess you should then add the stack trace as well. It is simply impossible that something that **is** a TaskInstance can't be casted to that type!

Comment: I am not getting any errors to include, please see the attached image in the question (obj),  I am getting the two objects in obj, I need one of them to caste to TaskInstance. 
Control not coming inside if statement since
         if(obj instanceof TaskInstance ) is failing

Answer (score 3):

First of all: you don't need to write down the generic type *twice*; starting with Java 7 we have the diamond operator; that allows you to write:

```
List<FirstTask> firstTasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then your problem is that you are doing an *unconditional* cast to FirstTask. Instead, do:

```
for (Object someTask : taskList) {
    if (someTask instanceof FirstTask) {
        firstTasks.add((FirstTask) someTask);
    }
}
```

for example. And of course, to take the most out of generics, the assumption would be that all your Task classes probably extend some base class, so taskList should more look like:

```
List<BaseTask> taskList = ...
```

Having `SomeCollection<Object>` is almost always a smell of bad design!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have updated the quesiton